# Android how can I assign custom parameters programmatically to my inflated view?

Tags: android, view, android-inflate

I've created a material style card for my android application in the file card_layout.xml and here is the code:

card_layout.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scheda_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/immagine_card2"
    android:background="@drawable/cardrect"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/immagine_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/salone"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titolo_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Titolo Card"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/citta_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Citta card"
    android:textSize="13sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/via_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Via card"
    android:textSize="13sp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emailicon2"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/emailicon" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Email card"
    android:textSize="13sp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/phoneicon2"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/phoneicon" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_card2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Telefono Card"
    android:textSize="13sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scopri_card2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="SCOPRI"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    `
```

I need to create multiple cards like that in my activity but they must have different android:text values on "Titolo Card", "Citta Card", "Via Card" , "Email card" and "Telefono Card" and a different image in the imageview on android:src="@drawable/salone"

The values I need are taken from a database so I've created a method which is called to add a card:

```
 public void addCard(String titolo, String citta, String via, String email, String telefono, String immagine ){

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_layout,   cardContainer,false);

    cardContainer.addView(view);

}
```

How can I set those parameters inside the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just access directly on the view:

```
public void addCard(String titolo, String citta, String via, String email, String telefono, String immagine ){

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_layout,   cardContainer,false);
    TextView txt;
    txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id._ID_OF_VIEW_);
    txt.setText(" text ");
    txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id._ID_OF_OTHER_VIEW_);
    txt.setText(" text ");

    ImageView img;
    img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id._ID_OF_IMAGE_);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable._DRAWABLE_);

    cardContainer.addView(view);

}
```